# csv file with different number of columns in rows

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

We are reading in a CSV file where there are different record formats.

The first records has 3 columns always. It's a header.

The others records have variable number of columns.

Separator is the pipe |.
The columns have fixed length (each column type have his fixed length).

I'm trying to parse this type of CSV file with FileHelpers:

```
*|060318|4       
1|Tom     |2 |605212999|02|663790000|02|T3_1018_RM    |0
2|Steve   |2 |605212999|02|663790000|02|T3_1018_RM    |0
3|Bob     |1 |605212999|02|T3_1018_RM    |0
```

CSV Columns:

```
ID|Name|Telephones Count|TelephoneNumber|TypeTelephone...|IDType|ProductType
```

Line 1 and 2 have 2 telephones (number and type):

```
     605212999|02
     663790000|02
```

Line 3 has 1 telephones (number and type):

```
     605212999|02
```

Is it possible use FileHelpers or another generic code?

I try similar like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
var csvList = new List<string[]>();
while(!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    String[] header = sr.ReadLine().Split('|');
    csv.Add(header); 
}
```

Using FileHelpers not applies `FixedLengthRecord`:

```
[FixedLengthRecord()]
public class Customer
{
    [FieldFixedLength(1)]
    public int Id;

    [FieldFixedLength(8)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string Name;

    [FieldFixedLength(2)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public int TelephoneCount;

    ....
    public string Phone1;
    public byte Phone1Type;

    public string Phone2;
    public byte Phone2Type;

    ...
    public string Phone9;
    public byte Phone9Type;

    [FieldFixedLength(14)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string IDType;

    [FieldFixedLength(1)]
    public int ProductType;
}
```

Or using http://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadWriteRecordByRecord/ neither applies

Answer (score 3):

FileHelpers *can* be used with variable-length records. The fixed-length attribute would be:

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]
```

I wouldn't use the fixed-length approach though as it would treat your delimiters as actual data. So instead you could use:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class Customer
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }

    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }

    [FieldOptional] // <-- 
    public string OptionalColumn { get; set; }

    [FieldOptional] // <-- 
    public string OtherOptionalColumn { get; set; }
}
```

With sample data:

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
data.AppendLine("12345|PETE PETERSON                 |01012001");
data.AppendLine("54321|SUSAN SMITH                   |11112011|Hello");
var customers = new FileHelperEngine<Customer>().ReadString(data.ToString());
```

Comment: There are many optionalcolumns. For sample: `Required Column 1, OptionalColumn1, OptionalColumn 2, , ...OptionalColumn N, Required Column 2, Required Column 3`

Comment: @Kiquenet you can give the properties of the optional columns any name you want, as long as you add the `[FieldOptional]` attribute before it. See the updated answer.

Comment: There is a column,that contains ***Number of telephones***. For example, ***2*** values, t hen the following columns are _telephone number and type telephone_ (`01 , 02 for mobile`). For example: `|2 |605212115|02|663794042|02|`

Comment: Sounds like that **column** is _redundant_ then?

Comment: I don't see what use that "number of telephones" column has, if you can determine the number of columns by the number of pipe chars on a row. The question does not mention this column btw, and it's 4 months old.

Comment: I don't see how FieldOptional is useful unless it's the last field. How would the parser know if the field exists or not if it's in middle of the column list??